# Start a local session, remotely

Tags: ssh, vnc

I dont want to enable auto login for various reasons. Is it possible to login to the desktop, from an ssh session, in order to then VNC into the desktop ? The issue is that I remotely turn on/off my pc remotely and on occassion I would like to gain access to the desktop.

Comment: You know, I did do a search and never found that page ! Maybe I wasnt looking properly, thanks for the pointer. Im going to play with Xvfb and x11vnc, see how I get on.

Comment: Yes, use a VNC server that allows separate sessions. FWIW, I highly suggest FreeNX, it is faster and more secure then any other VNC server.

Comment: I had a very quick play with Xvfb, couldnt get it working. Had a very quick play with x11vnc, got a session going that I could vnc into but only got a black screen with a mouse cursor. I only spent minutes playing and will check out x11vnc a bit more. Does FreeNX need an intermediary server, like teamviewer does ?

Comment: Thought I would put one final comment up here. I have used a dirrefent method to access my remote machine (don't know why I didn't so this earlier). Rather than connect into my desktop, I run a VM using virtualbox which can be fully controlled from the command line. I run the VM headless and simply RDP into that. OK, strictly speaking this puts me a little off topic, but works a treat !